# Join vector of strings to std::ostream (like boost::join)

Tags: c++, ostream, csv

I have a vector of strings and I want output it to stream (file stream, actually). And I want to have a delimiter between vector elements. There is a way to use standard `ostream_iterator`

```
std::vector <std::string> strs;
std::ostream_iterator<std::string> out_file_iterator ( out_file, delim );
std::copy ( strs.begin(), strs.end(), out_file_iterator );
```

I didn't like this way because there is a `delim` text after *each* element, but I don't need to have a `delim` after last element. I'd like to use something like `boost::join`. However `boost::join` returns string and my vector too large to output it to string.

What is most elegant way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a general solution (untested):

```
template<class T>
class ostream_join_iterator {
public:

    // Construct like an ostream_iterator.
    ostream_join_iterator(std::ostream& stream,
        const std::string& delimiter = "")
        : stream(stream), delimiter(delimiter), first(true) {}

    // Behave like an output iterator.
    ostream_join_iterator& operator++()    { return *this; }
    ostream_join_iterator& operator++(int) { return *this; }
    ostream_join_iterator& operator*()     { return *this; }

    // Output a delimiter before all but the first element.
    template<class T>
    ostream_join_iterator& operator=(const T& value) {
        if (!first) {
            stream << delimiter;
        } else {
            first = false;
        }
        stream << value;
        return *this;
    }

private:

    std::ostream& stream;
    const std::string delimiter;
    bool first;

};
```

You can use it like a regular `std::ostream_iterator`:

```
std::copy(strings.begin(), strings.end(),
    ostream_join_iterator<std::string>(file, delimiter));
```

Answer (score 2):

One way that works is to handle the last one separately. But don't think it's very *elegant*. Of course, you could wrap the ugliness in your own `join` function.

```
assert(strs.size() > 0);
std::ostream_iterator<std::string> out_file_iterator ( out_file, delim );
std::copy ( strs.begin(), strs.end()-1, out_file_iterator );
out_file << strs.back();
```

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant would be to write your own loop. Or a seperate function.

```
template<class Stream, class InIt>
void print_range(Stream& s, InIt first, InIt last, char const* delim = "\n"){
  if(first == last)
    return;
  s << *first++;
  for(; first != last; ++first){
    s << delim << *first;
  }
}
```

Comment: How about a quick test for empty ranges?

Comment: @Benjamin: Good point, though I think I'd rather have that as a precondition imposed on the user of `print_range`.

Comment: Hmm, I wasn't thinking "assert".  I was rather thinking of treating an empty range as perfectly valid, and simply printing nothing.  After-all, empty sets are quite common in the real world.

Comment: @Benjamin: There, I got convinced. :P After thinking this through, it all ends up with the same number of branch tests anyways, whether I treat the first element specially or not.

Comment: No, I think you were right.  There is an additional branch in this version.  e.g. With a range of size 1, there will be the initial test(which will fail), then you will print an element, then the test in the for loop (which will pass).  With your original version, there will only be the test in the for loop.  I would still prefer this version though.

Answer (score -1):

This is an idea with a functor

```
using namespace std;

struct add_delim_t {
  add_delim_t(const char *_delim) : delim_(_delim), is_first_(true) {}
  string operator () (const string &_val) {
    if (is_first_) { is_first_ = false; return _val; } else return delim_ + _val;
  }
private:
  const string delim_;
  bool is_first_;
};

transform(s.begin(), s.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout), add_delim_t(" , "));
```

The problem with this solution that it uses statefull predicate. Theoretically it means UB.

Answer (score -1):

There is an idea with Boost Function Input Iterator

```
using namespace std;

struct generator {
  typedef string result_type;
  generator(result_type _delim) : delim_(_delim), is_first_(true) {}
  result_type operator () () { 
    if (!is_first_)
      return delim_; 
    is_first_ = false; 
    return ""; 
  }
private:
  result_type delim_;
  bool is_first_;
};

template<class T>
struct reverse_plus : public binary_function<T, T, T> {
  T operator()(const T& _lhs, const T& _rhs) const { return (_rhs + _lhs); }
};

// output to file stream
transform
( strs.begin()
, strs.end()
, boost::make_function_input_iterator(generator(" , "), boost::infinite())
, ostream_iterator<string> out_file_iterator(out_file)
, reverse_plus<string>()
);
```