# Resolving circular dependency between concept and constrained template function

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I am trying to learn more about concepts. I ran into some problems with circular dependencies between concepts and constrained template functions, and I've reproduced these errors in a simple example.

---

I have a concept, `Printable`, that I want to be satisfied if and only if `operator<<` is defined on a type. I also have an overload of `operator<<` on vectors of printable types.

To my surprise, `std::vector<int>` is not considered `Printable`, even though `operator<<` works on it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
concept Printable = requires(std::ostream& out, T a) {
    out << a;
};

template <Printable T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    out << '[';

    for (std::size_t i {}; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        out << vec[i];
        if (i < vec.size() - 1) {
            out << ", ";
        }
    }

    return out << ']';
}


static_assert(Printable<int>); // This works as expected.
static_assert(Printable<std::vector<int>>); // This fails.

int main() { 
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << vec << '\n'; // This works as expected.
}
```

This fails on Clang++ 14.0.6_1 with the following message:

```
stack_overflow/problem.cpp:26:1: error: static_assert failed
static_assert(Printable<std::vector<int>>); // This fails.
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
stack_overflow/problem.cpp:26:15: note: because 'std::vector<int>' does not satisfy 'Printable'
static_assert(Printable<std::vector<int>>); // This fails.
              ^
stack_overflow/problem.cpp:7:9: note: because 'out << a' would be invalid: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
    out << a;
        ^
1 error generated.
```

So my question is: what can I do to make `std::vector<T>` considered `Printable` if `T` is `Printable`?

---

Notes:

- I believe this compiles fine as is with g++, but I recently screwed up my setup for GCC so I cannot confirm this at the moment. If this is true, I would love to know why it works for g++ but not clang++.

  - Update: Barry's comment reminded me that Compiler Explorer exists. I can now confirm that the above code compiles on g++ but not on clang++. I still am curious about why this difference exists.
- I believe I need to put the operator overload above the declaration of `Printable`. If I do this and remove the constraint, the code compiles fine. However, I want to keep the Printable constraint if possible, as I believe keeping constraints like this will simplify error messages in the future.

Comment: I suspect you are running afoul of ADL.

Comment: @wojand: Yes, with the static_asserts commented out, `std::cout << vec << '\n'` does find and use my implementation. It prints `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. (_Wait, where did they go? I swear I saw them ask about this..._)

Comment: Extremely minor side-note: You can avoid a test per loop to add the comma by moving the output of the first element outside the loop. Just add `if (!vec.empty()) out << vec[0];` before the loop, change the loop initializer to `std::size_t i = 1`, and the body of the loop can simplify to `out << ", " << vec[i];`, no need for a conditional or separate output statements each loop. Note that this sort of thing [is a solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9670680/364696) that could be made to work with arbitrary iterators if you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To my surprise, `std::vector<int>` is not considered `Printable`, even though `operator<<` works on it.

It doesn't. Not really anyway. When you say `std::cout << x;` works what you really mean is that you can write that expression from wherever and that works - "from wherever" including in the definition of `Printable`. And in the definition of `Printable`, it... doesn't work. Unqualified lookup doesn't find it and argument-dependent lookup doesn't find it either. The same will likely be true in most other contexts, unless you carefully add a `using operator<<;` in the appropriate place(s).

You could attempt to move the declaration of `operator<<` forward, so that the concept definition can see it - but that still wouldn't ultimately resolve the issue of any other code actually being able to call that operator. It can't *really* work unless this operator is declared in `namespace std`. And you're not allowed to add it in there.

But if you *could*, then this would work fine:

```cpp
namespace std {
    template <class T>
    concept Printable = requires (ostream os, T const var) { os << var; }

    template <Printable T>
    ostream& operator<<(ostream&, vector<T> const&) { ... }
}
```

---

Or just use `{fmt}`

Comment: I am a little confused when you say that no other code can actually call my operator. If I drop what I have into a header file `vector_print.h`, then anywhere I include that file I can use the operator, right?

Comment: @JackCasey You *can* use it, but only if you carefully add `using ::operator<<;` wherever you need it: https://godbolt.org/z/sjeGGnoPY

Comment: Ahh, that example helps a lot, thanks. Also, your answer helped me find a different solution to the core problem of making `static_assert(Printable<std::vector<int>>)` happy, which I'll detail below in a second.

Answer (score 0):

After some consideration of Barry's answer, I continued experimenting and found something that works:

---

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
void print(std::ostream& out, T a) {
    out << a;
}

template <class T>
concept Printable = requires(std::ostream& out, T a) {
    print(out, a);
};

template <Printable T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T>& vec) {
    out << '[';

    for (std::size_t i {}; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        out << vec[i];
        if (i < vec.size() - 1) {
            out << ", ";
        }
    }

    return out << ']';
}


static_assert(Printable<int>); // This works as expected.
static_assert(Printable<std::vector<int>>); // This works now.

int main() { 
    std::vector<int> vec {1, 2, 3, 4};
    std::cout << vec << '\n'; // This works as expected.

    // And to really prove it, this works too!
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec_of_vecs {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    std::cout << vec_of_vecs << '\n';
}
```

Clang compiles this, and the program outputs:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

As you can see, the trick is to have `Printable` rely on another function `print()`.

If I'm being honest, I still don't have a good way to explain *why* delegating the lookup of `operator<<` to another function helps here, but it does. I'd love if someone could help explain this.

Update:
This doesn't work. It compiles and runs find, but Printable is now useless since it always passes.